# Using same angular template with dynamic text

Tags: javascript, svg, angular8

I have created a angular template using svg (https://angular.io/guide/svg-in-templates) , so now i can repeat it the way i like at different places where i had image before . But i am facing a challenge as how to pass dynamic text content
which will be passed on to "text" tag inside the svg. So i have something like this

```
<div1><app-svg-template></app-svg-template></div1><!-- pass report title 1 here -->
<div2><app-svg-template></app-svg-template></div2><!-- pass report title 2 here -->
<div3><app-svg-template></app-svg-template></div3><!-- pass report title 3 here -->
```

i have tried to do something like this
{{reportName}}
and using "ng-content" inside  tag to some success , but it fails will long report names
as i am not able wrap it properly.
please suggest the best approach to solve this . I guess it will be basic usecase but not able to find a working solution . Better explain the approach a bit as i am new in angular . TIA.

Comment: If you showed us the code you have perhaps we'd understand why you have a problem with long report names. Note that SVG does not have native wrapping, if you want to wrap text the simplest way is to use HTML rather than SVG to display it.

Comment: report names are 50 chars or 60 chars long and they are going out of viewbox as they can't be wrapped . There is nothing much of code here but still here it is : <text id ="reportname" class="report-name"  transform="scale(1, -1)" x="768.93" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" y="-8400">
          <ng-content></ng-content><! -- here name can be 50-60 long char -->
          </text>

Comment: Then, as I said you should be using HTML here rather than SVG.

Comment: Please check this example for Property binding and two way binding example. Hopw this will help you to use/render same component with different text. https://stackblitz.com/angular/plylembprlb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html